# What type of inversion is in the following sentences? : Thee will I honor, praise and give glory

Tags: inversion

e.g:
Thee will I love, my Strength, my Tower 
thee shall I love in endless day

Comment: @Nguyen Huyen Welcome to English Language Learners. Just a recommendation from someone who's been using this site for a while - I think you'll have a hard time getting an answer for your question because it's not very clear what you're asking. How does the sentence in the question relate to the one in the title for you? Which one are you asking about. Can you add more detail to your question?

Answer (score 2):

There are several types of [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(linguistics)) that occur in modern English.  For example, [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion) occurs in [yes/no questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative#Syntax).

However, the sentences you listed are using a type of inversion that is archaic and/or poetic, and would not be found in standard modern English.

The standard word order of your sentences would be:

> (poetic inversion) Thee will I honor, praise and give glory.
>   (standard word order) I will honor thee, praise thee and give thee glory.
>
> (poetic inversion) Thee will I love, my Strength, my Tower.
>   (standard word order) I will love thee, my Strength, my Tower.
>
> (poetic inversion) Thee shall I love in endless day.
>   (standard word order) I shall love thee in endless day.

I think you're also asking how to identify that inversion is taking place.  These sentences are using [archaic 'thee'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou) which is the objective form and cannot be interpreted as the subject of the verb.  'Thee' must be interpreted as the object of the verb, so the use of 'Thee' as the first word of the sentence implies that there is inversion.  Furthermore, the inversion in your sentences is plausible, precisely because the archaic 'thee' and several other context clues indicate that this is poetic and archaic English.

With all that said, I haven't found a term for the specific type of inversion shown by these sentences.  The closest term I've found is [topicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization) which brings 'thee' to the beginning of the sentence.  However, topicalization alone may not be a sufficient explanation of these sentences, because it doesn't explain the order of the words "... will I ...".  To explain that, perhaps we could explain these sentences as showing [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion) and/or [V2 word order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order), in addition to topicalization.

Comment: I think the question is clear, and you answered it by giving the standard word order. I fail to see how the question could be clearer and how your answer could be clearer...

Comment: I dont know what type of inversion used in the above sentences it was before, so now I see they were using archaic style that is not popular at the present time.
I edited my question, is this question correct ? Could you spare a moment?

Comment: @NguyễnHuyền Now I understand that you're asking what type of inversion is shown here. I edited my answer to explain that I haven't found a term for it, although I found some related terms.